# c++ - how to know when the thread context switch happens?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Like the title says how do we know when does the context switch happens when using std::threads in c++

for example

```
void a()
{
   //some code
}                                    
void b(); 
{
   //some code 
}                                    

int main ()
{
  thread th1 (a);       
  thread th2 (b); 

  th1.join();                                        
  th2.join();                                       

  return 0;
}
```

is there a way to know when the O.S makes the thread switch and we could actually depict like print a or b when the respective function is processing.

Note: I've used mutexes and control variables putting a simple cout<<"a is being processed" on them doesn't necessarily depict the real context switch.

Comment: You don't. That's the operating system's job, to know when to switch thread contexts. And on modern, multi-CPU hardware, there may not even be a thread context switch, with a separate CPU is assigned to each thread, and everything runs concurrently. What problem are you trying to solve? No, not the one about knowing when there's a thread context switch, but the one you think the solution is to know when there's a thread context switch.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I just made a program with two threads and wanted to print what process is currently being processed

Comment: The point of threads is that they are independent streams of instructions, so it is not possible for the thread to detect context switches between them.    Obviously an operating system scheduler will manage/track such information, but will not make the switches evident to affected threads.  If you are trying to detect such a thing, you probably need to do some sort of synchronisation (e.g. critical section, mutex, use atomic variables) of access to shared data, or wait for threads to complete (e.g joining).

Comment: I'm sure that there is an operating system-specific resource you can use to see which threads are currently running. The problem is that by the time you obtain this, and manage to print it, a different thread may be running. This accomplishes absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 3):

There may not *be* a context switch to know about.

On a machine with two (or more) cores, both your threads may be running simultaneously, with no context switches happening at all until they finish.

Keep mind that *most* current machines have at least two cores, and machines with 4 to 8 cores are already fairly common. Assuming that code like this will lead to *any* context switches is basically obsolete. In theory it's been obsolete for a long time (i.e., there *have* been parallel machines for decades).

Now it's pretty thoroughly obsolete in practical fact--even if you get your new computers by scrounging through junk that others have given away or donated, chances are still pretty good that their old junk will have at least two cores, and four isn't out of the question at all.

Comment: Also keep in mind, @JerryCoffin, that no matter how many cores a CPU has, an OS under heavy enough load will switch threads. In other words, if this question stays in the teaching/demo-ing area, you can arrange for conditions to display thread context switches.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi: Oh, no question that context switches can, do, and will still happen--but depending on load, they can easily be rare enough that you might have to (for example) run the program several times before you see one happen (even assuming you write the code to detect one correctly).

Comment: "you might have to (for example) run the program several times before you see one happen" :D Or open enough Firefox tabs, all running "nyan cat" on full volume :D

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi: I doubt that the volume you set has much (any?) effect on CPU usage (other than convincing me to turn it off more quickly, thus negating the effect). :-)

Comment: :) well, speaking of on purpose arranged setup, replacing the speaker with one that draws a higher current might starve the CPU by overloading the PSU. But we'll need to move the discussion on EE site to explore the consequences :)

Answer (score 1):

> we could actually **depict** like print a or b when the respective function is processing.

**If this is meant only for demo/teaching purposes**

Let me use this metaphor: you have a black-box controller (the OS) that pushes current through two diodes (threads). Since you don't have any command over the controller, the only way to see which path your current flows is to replace your diodes by LED-es - in all moments time the current flow through them, they emit light. (note: as a LED may not be equivalent with the diode it replaces, you wouldn't want to sell the product which may blow up the magic smoke - that is to say "Don't use this technique outside diagnosis cases inside your lab")

In terms of your `a()` and `b()` functions, this translates into making them "emitting light" at every instruction they perform (or just enough of those instructions to achieve the demoed purpose).

So write a macro that wraps those instructions and, apart from having the instruction executed, they have a side effect you can use to detect which of the threads is running. *Mind you*: they can run in the same time on two different CPU cores.

---

The technique is usually called "instrumentation" and it is used (adapted for their particular cases) by, for example, performance evaluation tools.

Comment: your answer is good, I'll have a look at it. Can you provide a simple example of instrumentation if you know of any?

Comment: @AlberttheKing if you ask for tools using this technique, look at `gprof` and related as an example (one needs compile the program with `-pg` flag and the generated code will intercept the start/end execution of functions - gprof allows you to explore the timing data resulted from the execution). If you ask for an example on how to use this technique in your case, I might try to sketch something *after you confirm this is what you want*.

Answer (score 0):

You can't know and you have no reason to know.

One of the driving principles behind kernel / hardware thread and context management is specifically making this whole process invisible to you. There might not even be *any* context switches between your two threads (other threads on the system aside), if both are running on different cores.

If you're in a situation where you think you need to do this, you probably need to sit back and rethink your design, and familiarize yourself with the various synchronization constructs that are generally available for you to use.

Comment: If you debug the code you could actually see which thread is being processed next, so I wanted the user to see that switch

Comment: @AlberttheKing I think you are confusing a couple of things. No debugger will tell you which thread is being processed *next*. What they *can* tell you is a list of all the threads you have created, as well as *some of the threads that happened to be running right when you paused it*, and the debugger needs zero knowledge of when context switches happen (if they happen) to provide this info to you. The best you can provide to the user is the ID of a thread (not sure why you'd want to slam the user with context switch notifications anyways, which can happen hundreds of times per second).

Comment: Ya maybe Im taking debugging as being actual thread switchong

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the more abstract answers above, on POSIX systems, you can find out which core you're currently executing on with [`sched_getcpu()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sched_getcpu.3.html)

```cpp
#include <sched.h>

int current_cpu = sched_getcpu();
```

By monitoring this and observing changes, you can detect when your process has been moved between cores.  This can be useful in conjunction with setting cpu affinity.  However, it won't give any useful information if your process has been suspended and resumed on the same core.